# Unable to launch TestNG Test - Shows a pop-up dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

I'm trying to launch some TestNG tests in Eclipse, which were working earlier. But now it doesn't run at all, and shows a dialog saying 
"**Launching myclassname has encountered a problem.**"

It doesn't happen to all the tests in the package, but only to some of them.

What could be the reason? Any help to narrow down the problem would be really appreciated.

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching myclassname".
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MarkerAnnotation cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SingleMemberAnnotation
>       at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.TestNGMethodParameterVisitor.getParametersMap(TestNGMethodParameterVisitor.java:182)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.parseParameterNames(ParameterSolver.java:130)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.solveParameters(ParameterSolver.java:113)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.getParameterNames(ParameterSolver.java:91)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.util.param.ParameterSolver.solveParameters(ParameterSolver.java:60)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getLaunchSuites(ConfigurationHelper.java:416)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createVMRunner(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:296)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:161)
>       at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Comment: do you see any relate error in "Error Log" view, by navigating "Windows -> Show View -> Others -> Error Log" . I need more stack trace do diagnose this issue. BTW, what's Eclipse Version you used?

Comment: Can you provide the code portion? It seems that you you did some mistakes in any of your annotations.

Comment: Sorry for posting multiple comments. The error log was quite long for a comment. I'm using Eclipse Luna. Also, I could run the tests through my TestNG xml, so I'm assuming that the error is not related to the code.

Comment: @kanayikkaran You can update your question instead or continue here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/294

Comment: The issue was related to TestNG Eclipse plug-in and is fixed now. Available in beta update site. Thanks a lot @JulienHerr for directing to the right forum.